# Ansible for Windows

Tags: windows, ansible

I am trying to set up my ansible host to connect to windows.  However ping is failing with the following error:

sudo ansible win -m win_ping 
hostname | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "basic: HTTPConnectionPool(host='hostname', port=5986): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)", 
    "unreachable": true
}

pywinrm is installed on my linux box and WinRM is installed on the windows box.

Hosts file:

```html
[win]
systemname
[win:vars]
ansible_user=username
ansible_password=passord
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme=http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
```

Appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping it normally? Does the firewall allow winrm?

Comment: yes ping is successful from linux to windows.

Comment: and the firewall rules has "Allow WinRM HTTPS" for port 5986

Comment: Is winrm listening on `0.0.0.0`? (You can test it with `netstat -an`)

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5986           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: You do not have `hostname` in your inventory.  You have `systemname`.

Comment: i have a fqdn in the hosts file, i just didnt want to paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Windows Firewall (Domain, private and public networks) in the Windows box, fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check the WinRM Listener settings:

```
winrm enumerate winrm/config/Listener
```

If the output is what you expect, can you test a command on the local server as shown here:

```
winrs -r:http://server:5985/wsman -u:Username -p:Password ipconfig
```

Ansible has a good [reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#common-winrm-issues) on this topic as well.